# How to use gnu make to develop (or even get started with) MS DirectShow applications?

Tags: makefile, directshow, gnu

I was trying to build the DirectShow BaseClasses (in directory like C:\DXSDK\Samples\C++\DirectShow\BaseClasses) with gnu make instead of from within Visual Studio/nmake, but I had no luck. The SDK can be downloaded [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8279).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481713/how-to-get-started-with-directshow) is a similar question, but the answer is targeted to the VS environment.

If you're familiar with developing Microsoft DirectShow applications (in particular, building the baseclasses) using the gnu make tool, instead of the cumbersome apparatus Microsoft hands to your table, please help!

EDIT: I finally gave up using any "non-MS" way to develop under MS' framework.

Comment: What are the errors you are getting?

Comment: @selbie The problem is: I don't know how to write the Makefile for these baseclasses at all! In my limited knowledge of makefile, sources undergo a process and then an executable is produced. But in the case at hand, it seems that the final products should be two .lib files.

Comment: I've compiled strmbase.lib several times in different build environments (all of which were using the MS compiler). I'll have to dig up some old code to see which DEFINEs were getting set. I will try to get some suggestions for you later today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you think the Microsoft tools are cumbersome.  Both the command line and Visual Studio tools work great for me for building strmbase.lib in the past.  As a matter of fact, I seem to recall just installin the Windows SDK, navigating to the DShow library and typing "build" to get it made.

To compile strmbase.lib with a custom build environment:

Just create a Makefile like you would any other code library (.lif) from sources.  Individually compile all the .cpp files with an include path that points to the Windows SDK directory.  (i.e. the directory that contains  header file). Then package all the object files from the compiled source files into a library archive.

Optional: For a debug build, just make sure both _DEBUG and DEBUG are defined via your Makefile. (Avoid the case where one is defined, but not the other).  Some logic at the top of streams.h handles this for you.

Optional: If you want unicode strings, you should define both _UNICODE and UNICODE via your Makefile (same thing - avoid the case where one is defined but not the other).  If you don't have either defined in your Makefile, you don't have to worry abou this step.

Also, if I recall, there's some issue with one of the files that conflicts with a define in ATL. If you hit that, it's easy to fix.

I'm not sure what the other lib file is that you think.  Perhaps strmiids.lib?  If you don't already have that in the Windows SDK lib path, it's easy to generate that with some INITGUID defines.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. But I still could not get it right. For instance, `transip.cpp` is a cpp in the baseclasses directory. When I tried `g++ -c transip.cpp -I"C:\DXSDK\Include" -I. -L"C:\DXSDK\Lib"`, a lot of undeclared errors popped up.

Comment: What are the first set of errors do you get when you compile transip.cpp?  I don't see the Windows SDK INCLUDE directory in your command line above.

Comment: If you don't mind, please take a look at the compilation error log [here](http://pastebin.com/RNs7BK7k), generated by the same command. The directory DXSDK\Include is the DirectX Include directory. I also tried to add the Windows SDK Include directory, but I got 20k+ more lines in the error log... :(

Comment: Have you tried "the -E" compiler option for g++ so you can examine the preprocessor output? Likely, there's some keyword that isn't getting defined by the g++ compiler environment.

Comment: I looked at your compile logs and I suspect that there are both keywords and implicit DEFINES recognized and set by MSVC that aren't enabled in gnu. You can use the -E option to track down these problems and perhaps #ifdef some fixes around the issue. But one thing I know for certain - Microsoft definitely doesn't test their legacy SDK header files on gcc/g++.  Have you considered just doing the DirectShow specific portion of you project with MSVC and then having a simpler wrapper library abstraction so that your main project written in GNU can consume it?

Comment: Finally, just as an aside. As a long time Windows app developer with lots of Linux dev experience, it does not make much sense (to me) to attempt to use mix the GNU compiler with Windows SDK header files to build code that can only run on Windows. Perhaps it's puzzling simply because I've never tried it. But I don't understand hte motivation either given that you can get the MS compiler as a free download.